# need help to better understanding chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I just finish writing an alpha of a chrome extension that parsing Japanese from dictionary web page and present it as flash cards. It's a single js that pass on the DOM and parse all type of data.

Right now the extension is creating a div element inside the web page to store all the data, and I want to move it to a popup from my extension.

So I add a popup and clicked on the icon

```
  "browser_action": {
"default_icon": "icon19.png",
"default_title": "Tangorin extention is active",
"popup": "popup.html"
```

}

Nothing happened, so I think it's probably because I told him to open a specific page on my eventHandler on click, so I need something that will tell it to open the popup. I look out and found something that calls message to connect inside your extension.

So I followed google guild and did something like that in my eventHandler

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab)
{
    var newURL = "http://tangorin.com/examples/";
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });
});

chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
    if (request.greeting == "hello")
      console.log("message");
  });
```

Also, I think is called sending a message from a web page so I add permissions and something that will call it on my script.

```
  "externally_connectable": {
    "matches": ["*://*.tangorin.com/examples/*"]
  }
```

And something that will call it on my script.

```
function print_results() {
  //bla bla
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"});
}
```

And nothing happened, `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` doesn't trigger the function in the eventHandler.

Am I on the right track? Or there is a better way to make it open the popup?
I don't know much about extension dev yet, but I managed to make it work until now.

Thanks in advance, 
Or

**Edit**: maybe instead I can open the default popup when the user click on an object that as been created by the content script?

Comment: anything at all in the developer tools console to indicate any issue?

Comment: Chrome extension is the extra script that you want to run when a page loads. before making script run on as a extension run it on chrome script bar to see log and errors.

Comment: @Vinayk93 all the script works except the messaging parts.

Comment: @JaromandaX I see no errors in the console.

Answer (score 1):

1. List item
2. Create background script background.js .
3. Add in your minifet.json next :

> `"background": { "scripts":["background.js"] }`

4. In your background.js script add :

   ```
   chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
         function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
           if (request.greeting == "hello"){
              console.log("message");
              sendResponse({status:"Message delivered success!"});
           }          
   });
   ```
5. In your popup.html add script main.js with code :

   ```
      function print_results() {
         //bla bla
         chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"});
       }
   ```

And check this for better understanding https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging .
Hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks, I used this link for the example. my eventHandler is registered in the minifet.json `  "background": {
    "scripts": ["eventsHandler.js"],
    "persistent": false`, and in doesn't looks like the message is triggering something.

Comment: Also popup.html is not exist yet, I'm using js that is registered to run when I entered to the website

Comment: maybe instead I can open the default popup when the user click

Comment: Try use this chrome.runtime.sendMessage(extensionId, {yourData}, callback )